# Magento - Internal server error

Tags: cookies, magento-1.7, internal-server-error

I have a Magento site which has multistore setup. 
The problem is when we browse the frontend after a few page visits suddenly the site stops loading. When I look into the server access log, it shows response code 500 for the URL which was accessed last.
I am unable to reproduce the issue because the errorneous URL is not consistent.

If I would delete the cookie "**frontend**" set by Magento, the site works seamlessly again.
I don't know how I can narrow down the debugging considering the effect of "frontend" cookie. Can anyone please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you look in your mysql db to see if you had a bad url?  look at this article http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/internal-server-error-500-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion thetimmer. I had already looked into the DB. The base URLs are perfect. And the 500 error is not permanent, it pops sometimes only. Deleting 'frontend' cookie fixes the site back.

Comment: sorry, I'm probably still a little too new to Magento to comment but I understand the frustration and am rooting for you.  So it's different urls causing the issue?  does the log list the url each time so you can see why it's incorrect?  I ask because I implemented a fix last night for FedEx tracking where a semi colon was being inserted before an equal sign.